# Django Unittest that form field is required

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms, django-unittest

I'm am trying to test the form `field`s have or don't have the `required` attribute, but I don't know where to find it. This is what I have tried:

```
form.fields[field].widget.attrs['required']
```

But I get this `error`:

```
form.fields[field].widget.attrs['required']
KeyError: 'required'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance of field has `required` attribute:

```
form.fields[field].required
```